# Passing arraylist object servlet to jquery ajax method

Tags: jquery, servlets

In my servlet code i don't know to pass Arraylist object to jquery ajax

in my servlet code:

```
 String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if(action.equals("a")){
        ArrayList<BeenTwoFields> al = new ArrayList<BeenTwoFields>();
        BeenTwoFields beFields = new BeenTwoFields();

        beFields.setAge(20);
        beFields.setName("Raj");
        al.add(beFields);

        String msg = "This is servelet example";
        response.setContentType("text/html:charset=UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(msg);
```

And my jsp page:

```
  <script> 
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
          url: "Servelet?action=a",
          success: callback
       });  
      });
   });

    function callback(data, status)
       {
        $("div").html(data);
       }
   </script>
```

Comment: `json` is an option for you

Comment: need clarification . can you help anybody.